# Куда записываются логи iptables c NFLOG

Tags: linux, iptables

Написал 2 правила iptables для отладки:

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT --destination 8.8.8.8 -p icmp -j NFLOG --nflog-group 1 --nflog-prefix "IPTABLES DROP: INFORMATION"
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT --destination 8.8.8.8 -p icmp -j DROP"
```

Должно работать так. Отправляю пинг на адрес 8.8.8.8, пакет попал на первое правило записал в лог, дошел до следующего правила и дропнул пакет. Пакеты дропает. Но ни в один лог не пишет. Dmesg,syslog ни одной строки. Если делаю вместо NFLOG, LOG то все записывается без проблем. Куда в данном случае NFLOG логирует всю информацию? Правила расположены в порядке что сперва пакет проходит через правило с логированием, а потом только в DROP